# Configuracion de un Proyecto en Next Js

Tags: reactjs

estoy empezando a estudiar el framework Next Js y no estaria pudiendo configurar bien el proyecto. Mas que nada el archivo _app.js para carga de estilos y importaciones de paquetes a utilizar. Y el archivo next.config.js.
Y que seria eso de la funcion de getInitialProps
Global CSS cannot be imported from files other than your Custom . Please move all global CSS imports to pages/_app.js.
Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/css-global. Ese fue el error que me tiro cuando importe un paquete.
Si me pueden decir como seria la configuracion completa de base de un proyecto en este framework mejor.

Comment: `getInitialProps` no se recomienda para las versiones 9.3 o superiores de Next.js (ahora Vercel). El problema del import lo solucionas importando CSS desde un solo lugar (`_app.js`). Si recién estás empezando, pegate una vuelta por el [tutorial](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/create-nextjs-app) la documentación es muy buena.

Comment: Dale, gracias Juan. saludos